# Как правильно решить упражнение из книги Эрика Мэтиза "Изучаем Python 3е издание", главе по сортировке, задача 3.8:

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, reverse

Задание заключается в том, чтобы используя функцию sorted() вывести список в обратном алфавитном порядке без изменения порядка исходного списка.

```py
from audioop import reverse
from itertools import count


pets = ['gekko', 'bird', 'cat', 'dog', 'rat']
print(pets)

print(sorted(pets))

print(pets)

z = sorted(pets)
print(z.reverse())

print(pets(reverse=True))
```

Как ни переставляй `reverse=True`, вывод выдает такую ошибку:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Я не понимаю, вроде бы через reverse=True единственный способ вывода списка в обратном порядке без его изменения, но как ни подхожу к решению, всё никак не могу найти правильный подход, спасибо всем кто поможет и извиняюсь за возможно примитивный вопрос.

Comment: Откуда Вы вообще такую конструкцию выдумали? Учитывая что pets это список `pets(reverse=True)`

Comment: Матерь божья, кода ж вы доки то читать начнете? ... Хотя-бы по стандартной библиотеке... https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/

Comment: `print(sorted(pets, reverse=True))` Функция `sorted` с параметром `reverse=True` вернет вам отсортированную в обратном порядке копию объекта не изменяя сам объект

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще можно вывести список в обратном порядке при помощи [срезов](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html), конкретно — `[::-1]`. К тому же `reverse = True` не может использоваться для списков, это используется для `sorted()`.

```py
pets = ['gekko', 'bird', 'cat', 'dog', 'rat']

print(sorted(pets, reverse=True))

z = sorted(pets)
print(z[::-1])
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, были мысли насчёт решения при помощи срезов, но хотелось всё таки узнать решение используя sorted и reverse=True.

Comment: Сорян за предыдушее, под топиком писать хотел, постом промазал

Comment: @Faverave пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить данный ответ как верный, если он Вам помог ;)

Comment: @Namerek бывает, к тому же я Ваш комментарий только сейчас увидел — в Брест на маршрутке ехал :)